# SNAKES: Active Contour Model

Tags: algorithm

I got the code of Snakes algorithm from here (Implemented in MatLab)

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28109-snakes-active-contour-models

when you give it the initial indices surrounding the contour, It runs perfectly. but, unfortunately that isn't what I want.

Imagine that there is a mountain, I want to detect it's contour. But, I only have the index of the top of the mountain. So, the initial indices are the indices surrounding this pixel. But when running the algorithm, the snake is getting smaller and smaller till vanishing.

I want the snake to grow up till it founds the contour. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but I have done a little reading on this topic. From what I understand many snake algorithms tend to shrink in the absence of any image forcing because they punish the first derivative (the integral of |x'|^2) and that inadvertently punishes area.

If you can access it, they talk about this problem in this paper and try and alter it to get an expanding snake by adding a volume term to the cost function.

http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/s00791-012-0178-8

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to increment the weight of External Forces (the force field generated by the mountain contour upon the snake points) and decrease the weight of Internal Forces (the elasticity of the snake, the "rubber band" effect).

If you do that, the snake will be less elastic (less of a rubber band) and more plastic (more like a string of beads).